# Prove $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in{N}$ for all $a,b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am trying to prove the above with the conditions that N is normal to G and $G/N$ is abelian.

So then for $Na,Nb\in{G/N}, NaNb=NbNa$.  But $NaNb=Nab=Nba$, so then we know $ab=ba$, so G is abelian.

So if $ab\in{G}, N=abN(ab)^{-1}=abN(ba)^{-1}=baNa^{-1}b^{-1}....$ and i'm getting lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $G/N$ is abelian, for all $a,b\in G$ we have $NaNb=NbNa$, so $Nab=Nba$. It **does not** follow that $ab=ba$, but rather that $Naba^{-1}b^{-1}=N$, i.e. that $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in N$.

Comment: Wait, so this just hit me...in G/N, N is the identity?  So then $N=Nab(Nab)^{-1}=NabNb^{-1}a^{-1}=NabNa^{-1}b^{-1}=Naba^{-1}b^{-1}$?  and what is $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Comment: An *element* of $N$...

Comment: Oh, i see....any element of n implies that Na=N if a is in n?  Was my math right in the previous comment?

Comment: Yes, it was correct